# Ошибка при вводе float

Tags: java, float, scanner

Мой код:

```
import  java.util.Scanner;
public class oClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner fx = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Введите свой земной вес");
       float Earth = fx.nextFloat();
       float Loon = (float) (Earth * 0.17);
       System.out.println("Ваш вес на луне составляет " + Loon + "кг. Приятного полёта!");
    }
}
```

Когда я ввожу целое число, то всё работает хорошо.
Но когда я ввожу десятичное число(float), у меня появляется ошибка

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2345)
    at com.company.oClass.main(oClass.java:7)
```

Почему это происходит, ведь я указал тип переменной и тип вводимого числа float.

Comment: При чём тут метка scanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо используйте тот символ разделителя целой и дробной части, который принят в вашей стране (для России это запятая), либо явно указывайте локаль:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```